# Rails root permalink routing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

In Rails, the standard routing to objects is nested to a Model's name, `example.com/model/object_id`.

Is it anyhow possible to access objects without the Model part, so `example.com/object_id` shadowly accesses `example.com/model/object_id`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rails includes routes like you said. You can add `constraints` to determine object_id is integer or string.

```
get '/:id', to: 'articles#show', constraints: { id: /^\d/ }
```

This is for more information about [routes constraint](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#segment-constraints).

Answer (score 1):

What you are first describing are the RESTful routes provided by the resources template in the rails router.

You can define different routes in the config/routes.rb file.

And for resources, you can provide a `path` option, where you can define a path.

```
resources :models, path: "/"
```

Will provide models resources at the route path. So a GET request to "/" would fire the "models#index" action and "/1/edit" would delegate to "models#edit"